# Animating imageview takes time for first time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am animating the ImageViews then the user taps a button. I have more than 40
 images. The code I have used is

```
arr3 =  [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Aperture_00000.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Aperture_00001.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Aperture_00002.png"],
...
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Aperture_00023.png"], nil];

imgv.animationImages = arr3;
imgv.animationDuration=2.0f;
imgv.animationRepeatCount =1;
```

The method to start the animation is:

```
-(void)animate {
    [imgv startAnimating];
}
```

But it takes a lot of time when the user presses the button for the first time. What could be the solution for this?

Comment: What is the reason for giving 1.png,2.png.. in a single [UIImage Named: ] block??

Comment: It takes a long time to load all the images, also it will take a lot of memory to load those images. You could load the images in an array when the view gets loaded. This will speed up the loading time.

Comment: i have used the array in viewdidload itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is following code:

```
arr3 =  [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Aperture_00000"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Aperture_00001"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png",@"2.png",@"3png",@"4.png",@"5.png",@"6.png",@"7.png",@"8.png",@"9.png",@"10.png",@"11.png",@"12.png",@"13.png",@"14.png",@"15.png",];
```

What you can do is load this array somewhere else.

Note : This is a very memory consuming way of loading the images. Your app will definitely crash after you visit this class 2-3 times. Instead of this use some alternative. The easiest alternative I can suggest is load a image on UIImageView and change the image periodically. It'll give you animation effect.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you rather doing it programmatically you should create animated gif image from the images. Here is online tool you can set speed and other parameters
http://picasion.com/

and use 
https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone
UIImageView category to display that gif image in that case you can save your CPU time.

Unhide the imageView when you want to play animation and hide when you want to stop.

I would suggest to give that at least a try.

Comment: Thanks for replying but how can i save the image and show it from main bundle

Comment: once you get your animated gif image, add it to your project and open project settings(Targets) > BuildPhases > copy Bundle Resources, there you can add the .gif file to your main Bundle and in code you should use <filename>.gif to access it

Comment: i have created an animated png but when i try to save the image it is not the animated image ?completly stuck here

Comment: have you downloaded that UIImageView category from https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone you need to show gif image in that UIImageView. Standard UIImageView in UIKit will not show animated image